# How can I bind a data inside a style?

Tags: xaml

> This XAML tag doesn't work:

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
```

---

> in this XAML code:

```
<Style x:Key="textBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />-->
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Background="AliceBlue" Content="Input Error"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

> I want to pass (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent data of a TextBox in a Label inside ToolTip property

Answer (score 0):

Using `RelativeSource Self` on a `Label` will get you the Label as the source, whereas you want the `TextBox`. Try a `RelativeSource FindAncestor`:

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
```